# HQL find objects with intersecting sublist including size

Tags: hql, intersection, sublist

hi i'm using hibernate 4 and try to find a HQL

a simple one to OneToMany:

Mainobject

```
@Entity
public class MainObject {
 @OneToMany
   List<SubObject> list;
}
```

Sub

```
@Entity
public class SubObject {
}
```

Now i have a List of SubObject. How can i find all MainObjects which conain at least two SubObjects of my list?